# Getting error when calling function: TypeError: this.myFunction is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following simplified function:

```
   public constructPoints() {
       mapArray.push("hello");      
    }
```

I'm calling the function from two spots:

```
 protected onDataSourceLoaded() {
    this.constructPoints();   
 }
```

AND

```
public OnSourceChanged(source) {   
    this.pageSource = source; 
    //this.onDataSourceLoaded();
    this.constructPoints();   
}
```

In the same file, I have this code block where OnSourceChanged is referenced:

```
  const sourceNavContext:SourceNavContext = {
      Items: this.sourceNavItems,
      Context: this.fieldFormContext,
      onRecordChanged: this.OnSourceChanged 
    };
```

OnDataSourceLoaded is a function that's being inherited from a base class:

```
 protected abstract onDataSourceLoaded()

//and in that base class there's also this:


 private wireupDataLoadedSubscription() {
    let subscription
      = this.dataLoadedNotifier.subscribe(next => this.onDataSourceLoaded());
    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
  }
```

HERE'S MY QUESTION:  When I call this.constructPoints from onDataSourceLoaded, it does what it's supposed to do.  When I call it from OnSourceChanged, I get the following error:  **TypeError: this.constructPoints is not a function**

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  As you can see, I've commented out a line in the last code snippet where this.onDataSourceLoaded is called.  If I uncomment this line, I get the same error but for this function.

Comment: Can you post the whole file.

Comment: I'd rather not because the naming is quite specific so I don't want to post anything secret.  Plus the file is really big.  But, I can add to the post here.  What would help?

Comment: Where are these two methods getting called from?

Comment: Just added that to the description.

Comment: You can try `onRecordChanged: this.OnSourceChanged.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the function to someone else and they call it without passing you the `this` parameter you expect. Try using an arrow function to capture`this`

```
const sourceNavContext:SourceNavContext = {
       Items: this.sourceNavItems,
       Context: this.fieldFormContext,
       onRecordChanged: s => this.OnSourceChanged (s)
 };
```

In JavaScript `this` is determined by the caller not by where the function is declared. See [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/this.html) and [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html) for more

Comment: Awesome.  That fixed it.  Thanks so much!   So the issue was that this took the context of the calling class?

Comment: @kickinchicken not even the calling class.. it all depends on how it was called. If you have a variable`fn` containing a function, if you call it `fn()` `this` will be the global window, if you call it `fn.call(whatever)` then`this` will be `whatever` all depends on the caller